# How to grab all the site links recursively by entering domain name?

Tags: php

How to grab all the site links recursively by entering domain name in PHP? Please give me some idea.

Comment: Google is your friend!

Comment: @Rizier123: Any idea that works fast and recursively?

Answer (score 0):

For grab the all link of site you need to use Simple Html Dom. here is demo link.
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Example : If you want to get all link of the website.

$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/'); // Create DOM from URL or file

// For Find all links

foreach($html->find('a') as $element){

```
   echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Not grab all links, just grab "useful" links by designing a algorithm to evaluate.And set the depth of recursion.

Comment: Am looking for something like XML sitemap. any idea?